# React react-beautiful-dnd having some glitches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

My code is functional, but the draggables are glitchy. The idea is to be able to drag items from the horizontal bar into the grid below. Sometimes everything works fine. However, sometimes when you drag from the top, the draggables to the left jump down for a second. It also happens when you drop a draggable outside the grid. I made a code sandbox, if anyone has any ideas that would be amazing!

https://codesandbox.io/s/kgp-2vy6c7?file=/src/App.js